# java 11 HttpClient send header then body

Tags: java, httprequest, httpclient, head

I want to use Java 11 HttpClient and send header first, check response and if response is OK then send the body.

How can I send header only?

this is my current code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .authenticator(Authenticator.getDefault())
                .build();
    
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder("someEndpoint)
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, "someApiKey)
                .build();

HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

However with such httpResponse I understand I send the body.

Comment: What do you mean by "sender header first"? Which HTTP method would this request use?

Comment: to send two separate request: HEAD first then request with Body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the header comes first in requests.

What you asked is, The first request with header and then with a body are two different requests. A single request can't be broken this way.

If you are talking about, Http HEAD method usage, then
The HEAD method asks for a response identical to that of a GET request, but without the response body.

The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that would be returned if the HEAD request's URL was instead requested with the HTTP GET method. For example, if a URL might produce a large download, a HEAD request could read its Content-Length header to check the file size without actually downloading the file.

an example to use HEAD method:-

```
var httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .build();
    var requestHead = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .method("HEAD", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())    
            .uri(URI.create("https://www.test.com"))
            .build();
    val httpResponse = httpClient.send(requestHead, BodyHandlers.discarding());

HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();

        headers.map().forEach((key, values) -> {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", key, values);
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I want to send two separate requests: first HEAD only then BODY

Comment: After performing HEAD request, you can verify the HEAD responses and further trigger the API call such as GET, POST etc. using 
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());